# Slow execution time for Kohana static ORM method

Tags: php, mysql, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

I have a Kohana 3.3 application, running on WAMP (PHP 5.4.3) which uses a static function to get a list of recent articles. When I load the page, the Application Execution time (via Kohana Profiler) is **6.7 seconds**. When I load the same page without calling the get_recent method (passing an empty array) the Application Execution time is **0.3 seconds**.

This indicates that this static method is causing a problem. I have run the raw MySQL and it takes **1.4 seconds**.

This is the code inside the method:

```
$articles = self::factory('user_articles')
                ->join('articles', 'INNER')->on('user_articles.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                ->order_by('user_articles.created_at', 'ASC')
                ->limit(10)
                ->group_by('articles.id')->find_all();
```

There is an index on `user_articles.article_id` and on `articles.id`. Is there anything else I can do to optimize the query or speed up the execution time?

Answer (score 0):

You could add index on `created_at` - check with raw SQL if it helps or not.
It maybe also good idea not to use ORM and try to run a DB Builder query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get last query by `echo Database::instance()->last_query` and try MySQL `EXPLAIN`. It will show you, which indexes are used.

PS: How many rows do you have in `articles` and `users`?